# Where is Teamviewer installed?

Tags: teamviewer

I have installed TeamViewer but where is it installed and how can I run it?

Comment: I would definitely make such an urgent message more clear, what is actually the question, where it is installed? How you can run it?

Comment: How did you install it? [edit] your question with the details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use whereis and which commands, for example:

```
which teamviewer
```

Output should be full path to teamviewr file, for example "/usr/bin/teamviewer". To start it, just enter that path in terminal:

```
/usr/bin/teamviewer
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `whereis` and `which` commands as stated above.

Or go into your **dash** (Clicking the top icon in your launcher on the right - or pressing that shiney **windows button on your keyboard**) and **start typing "teamviewer"**. The teamviewer icon should show up and you will be able to run it.